# Intelij IDEA ssh-key git repository connection denied

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I couldn't find issue like mine with a solve so I need your help.

In Git Bash I can get access with ssh git@specifiedip

I added public key to GitHub and I can get answer with ssh -T git@github.com
Hi username! You've successfully authenticated ...

I get my SSH-Key generated with PuTTy Gen.
My .ssh folder contains id-rsa and id-rsa.pub files.
I added `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa` to my ssh-config file.

I can clone repository with Git Bash, but I cant clone it with simple git command ie. in intelij IDEA console.

But I can't clone my repository in IntelliJ.
It shows SSH Keyboard Interactive with a Password field. I really don't know what can cause it, and how to make IntelliJ read my ssh-keys...

[Password field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkm0O.png)

[After test error field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paBPH.png)

Comment: I got exactly the same issue. I'll let you know when I figure out how to fix.

Comment: please see my answer to @rootkonda answer

Answer (score 0):

Configure the SSH executable as "Native"

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/user_images/0U1soQH33wre6Fs7piKLaQ.png

If that doesnt work then you can try this also

In the "C:\ Program Files\Git\ cmd" folder you will find the file "start-ssh-pageant.cmd"

Before launching it is necessary to create an environment variable:
Name: SSH_AUTH_SOCK
Value: C: \ Users \ username \ .ssh \ .ssh-pageant-username

Comment: There is no such option in IntelliJ IDEA as on the screen ( I saw it in other threads similar to this one ), running start-ssh-pageant.cmd didn't solve anything as well

Comment: I can find it right now in my system. Did you check the preferences and searched for Git ?

Comment: In newer versions of IntelliJ it's by deafult and there is no such option in settings

Comment: Yes I did. Answer is trivial. C:\Users\---------\.ssh my rsa file was named using - instead of _ so it was looking like id-rsa not id_rsa. I noticed this by using GitGui and and I saw it don't see my key either

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have multie account in your env.
If you can git pull in the git bash, then
add or copy a file named "config" to your c:\users\xxx.ssh.
Just like this:

```
Host github.com
 hostname github.com
 User xxx
 IdentityFile C:\Users\xx\.ssh\github_rsa

Host gitee.com
 hostname gitee.com
 User xxx
 IdentityFile C:\Users\xx\.ssh\id_rsa

Host 192.168.3.194
 hostname 192.168.3.194
 User xxx
 IdentityFile C:\Users\xx\.ssh\id_ed25519
```